# how to change the default text of application delete in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, delete-file

hi i want to change the text of the iPhone application deletion text `Deleting “Application" will also delete all of its data.` to `“Deleting “Application" will also delete all of its data.” on the next line include “This includes your data of server.....”` here some text also will come dynamically from application side. can it is possible?

and i also want to fire an URL after deleting my application from iPhone so i can know which user has deleted my application from iPhone.

can i do like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the delete app message and there is no way to tell iOS the call an URL after/on deleting an app.

When iOS delete's an app there is no method that gets called that you can access.